How to non-interactively move an earlier commit to the first one?
Each commit contains changes to only one file. The starting state:
* 248e458 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) A.txt
* 2dd589d B.txt
* cf47156 A.txt
* 38d0f87 B.txt

The question: how to move 2dd589d B.txt (last modifications to B.txt) to the top ? Moving 2dd589d B.txt in this case doesn't change the working tree.
* 2dd589d (HEAD -> master, origin/master) B.txt
* 248e458 A.txt
* cf47156 A.txt
* 38d0f87 B.txt

The goal is to first move this commit to first and then --amend it with the next commit that contains the changes to B.txt. So I can keep changes introduced in 2dd589d B.txt and add some introduced in 5a61192 B.txt.
Desirable result after commit --amend -m B.txt:
* 5a61192 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) B.txt
* 248e458 A.txt
* cf47156 A.txt
* 38d0f87 B.txt

So far I tried:
git rebase --onto cf47156 2dd589d

But this changes the working tree and removes all changes introduced by 2dd589d B.txt.

https://words.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/

Thanks, @phd Modifying EDITOR or GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR would be one solution. Git commit --fixup however does not change the commit location.

git commit --fixup creates a new commit which git rebase --interactive --autosquash later semi-automatically reorders to the correct place determined by the commit subject.

@phd You don't need to use --interactive together with --autosquash in newer versions of git :)

I would suggest:
# starting from a clean worktee with all
# changes stashed or committed:
git reset --hard cf47156
git cherry-pick 248e458 2dd589d


Bingo @LeGEC ! The best script-friendly non-interactive solution.
